# core data saving context

Tags: ios, core-data

I am only seeing the saved context after I restart my app. I have two view controllers, one that allows a user to save a core data record and the other to display. When I save a new record, then go to the table view to see all the records created, I do not see the new record. This is how I create a record:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Property *myProperty = [NSEntityDescription
                            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Property"
                            inManagedObjectContext:context];
    myProperty.aptDescription = curProperty.description;
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    [appDelegate saveContext];
```

And then i retreive it doing this:

```
ATAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ATAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Property" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    self.myProperties = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

But like I said the new object is not shown when I go back into the table view immediately after creating the record. What is the issue?

Comment: You don't need to save the context twice. Log the `error` variables you're using.

Comment: Are you getting any errors back, are you reloading the table data?

Comment: Use a fetchedResultsController in conjunction with your UITableView - see here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are not implementing the delegate methods of the `NSFetchedResultsController` properly. Although you did not share any of your view code so it is impossible to be certain.

In addition, after a save you are not checking the `BOOL` return from the `-save:`. You should always, *always*, **always** check that `BOOL` and at least log the error.  You could be throwing an error and never know it.